# Undefined array key error while uploading file to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I created a registration form. Also, i want to add a profile picture. However, my codes gives an error.

Warning: Undefined array key "fileupload" in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\register.php on line 29

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\register.php on line 29

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\register.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\db\register.php(30): file_get_contents('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\register.php on line 30

Line29 =  $fileName = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
Line30 =  $picture = file_get_contents($fileName);

How can I fix that?

```
<?php $fileName = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
 $picture = file_get_contents($fileName);
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">First Name</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="fName" rows="1" required></textarea>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $fNameErr; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="lName" rows="1"></textarea>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $lNameErr; ?></span>
</div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Claim Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="claimPassword">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $claimPasswordErr; ?></span>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $differentPasswordErr; ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" value="1-(555)-555-5555" name="telephone" rows="1"></textarea>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $telephoneErr; ?></span>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $telephoneErr2; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Department</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="department" rows="1"></textarea>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $departmentErr; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Institution</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="institution" rows="1"></textarea>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $instErr; ?></span>
</div>
 
  <div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Pick a profile picture</label><br>
    <input name="fileupload" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" required><br><br>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $pictureErr; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="exampleFormControlTextarea1">
  <label for="example-date-input" class="form-label">Date of birth</label>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $birthErr; ?></span>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2021-01-01" name="birth">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Gender</label>
  <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" name="gender">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Female
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" name="gender2" >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
   Male
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" name="gender3" >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
   I do not want to say
  </label>
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $genderErr; ?></span>
</div>

</div>

<br>

  <button type="submit" name= "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
  <br><br>
  <a href="login.php">Do you have an account? Click here to sign in.</a>

</form>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I can also add insert sql codes if you want..

Comment: The error says `Undefined array key "fileupload"` which means you're accessing the page without a file having been uploaded, which is generally a problem when you use the same page for both the GET request (in this case to display the form) and the POST request (to process the result of the form). Usually the code that handles the upload is separate from the view that contains the form as to not have too much going on in a single view file

Answer (score 1):

First issue is trying to access an uploaded file before the form submit happens. The first lines of your file could be changed to

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES['fileupload'])) {
 $fileName = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];
 $picture = file_get_contents($fileName);
}
?>
```

But you'll still get an error because you're referencing the `name` property of `$_FILES['fileupload']` - which will give you the actual filename, not the path to the file.

Use `tmp_name` which gives you a full system path to the file.  In short, access your uploaded file like this:

```
$picture = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name']);
```

Here is what the $_FILES` object looks like (which will be different values for you depending on the type of file etc:

```
[fileupload] => Array
        (
            [name] => MyFile.txt (comes from the browser, so treat as tainted)
            [type] => text/plain 
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o (could be anywhere on your system, depending on your config settings, but the user has no control)
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK  (= 0)
            [size] => 123   (the size in bytes)
        )
```

Comment: The error is "Undefined key `fileupload`", not `name`.

Comment: Thx - I revised, all that stuff about `name` would become OP's next error, so its still helpful